# About ++ to concate things

Tags: haskell

Given the following function signature:

```
concatThings :: (Show a) => a -> String -> String
concatThings any str2 = str2 ++ (show any)
```

If run `concatThings "there" "hi"`, then result will be: `"hi\"there\""`, but what I want is just `"hithere"`.

How can I still get "hithere" with this function signature?

Comment: You don't want to `show str1`; `str` is already a string, so just do `str2 ++ str1`.

Comment: I know, but I have some other cases where the first argument is not type of String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the string in a new type and provide a simple Show instance for it:

```
newtype PartialString = PartialString String

instance Show PartialString where
    show PartialString str = str
```

and then pass in a wrapped string to the `concatThings` function:

```
let pstr1 = PartialString str1 in concatThings pstr1 str2
```

Answer (score 4):

With this function signature, you can't. You must either get rid of the `show`, reducing the function to

```
concatStrs :: String -> String -> String
concatStrs = flip (++)
```

or introduce a new type class to replace `Show`.